# Default page when clicked gives error

Tags: configuration

When the default page of a shared library is clicked it throws an error:

> "ERROR
>
> An unexpected error has occurred.
> Troubleshoot Issues with Windows SharePoint Services"

We are able to access all the other links, only when accessing the default page its throwing this error

The page contains webparts.

Comment: Have you checked ULS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the ULS (SharePoint log files) if you have access to them or the EventVeiwer on the server.

In case you don't, do as follows:

In the URL add this at the back: `?contents=1`.

Example: http://www.mysharepointsite.com/default.aspx?contents=1

This will open a page with a list of current webparts on the page.
Delete the webparts and insert them again one by one untill the page fails. Then you'll know which webpart is causing the error.

If the page still throws an error while not having any webparts on it, if you have publishing features activated, it's most likely the pagelayout that the page uses that causes it.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I dont have the access to ULS.
I deleted the webparts and inserted them again, still no use.
I am sure the pagelayout isn't throwing this error.

Comment: @user9432 If you did that then I don't understand how come you don't know which webpart causes the error?